# add new column to existing Composite Unique Key

Tags: mysql, unique-constraint, composite-key, alter, unique-index

I have table named "**room**" , and it has the following composite unique key

```
room_acId_levelId_year_name_unique
```

formed from FOUR columns :

```
acId
levelId
year
name
```

And I want add column `isLevel` to that key without drop and recreate it

The new key should like this:

```
room_acId_levelId_year_name_isLevel_unique
```

with the following columns :

```
acId
levelId
year
name
isLevel
```

> Note that I just want to ALTER the key , not to DROP and create it again 
>    . Also two columns **acId** and **levelId** are foreign keys.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I solved the problem with the following steps:

1. Show index keys for my table **room**

   ```
   SHOW CREATE TABLE room;
   ```
2. I have to drop those foreign keys **acId** and **levelId**

   ```
   ALTER TABLE room DROP FOREIGN KEY room_acid_foreign;
   ALTER TABLE room DROP FOREIGN KEY room_levelid_foreign;
   ```

   (*Remember to use the key names you got on query in step one*)
3. Now I can drop my unique key **room_acId_levelId_year_name_unique**

   ```
   ALTER TABLE room DROP INDEX room_acId_levelId_year_name_unique;
   ```
4. Add again my two foreign keys again

   ```
   ALTER TABLE  room
   ADD FOREIGN KEY (sAcID) REFERENCES SAC(id)
   ON UPDATE CASCADE
   ON DELETE RESTRICT;

   ALTER TABLE  room
   ADD FOREIGN KEY (levelId) REFERENCES Level(id)
   ON UPDATE CASCADE
   ON DELETE RESTRICT;
   ```
5. Add my new key of five columns

   ```
   ALTER TABLE room
   ADD UNIQUE KEY 
   room_acId_levelId_year_name_isLevel_unique 
   (acId, levelId, year, name, isLevel);
   ```

I hope this will help someone else.